# How to refresh fragments 'onResume?'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to refresh fragments from an Actvitiy. (Let's call the activity A)
Activity A contains the fragments.

When I finish Activity B then Activity A should refresh the fragments.

I was thinking this would be done in onResume? I tried simply restarting the activity through an intent but that's not usability friendly.

So how do I refresh fragments when I resume an activity?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"?  Do you mean you want to reload data, or do you mean you want to cause A to be redisplayed, or ?

Comment: … what do you mean by "refresh fragments"?!

Comment: Basically I want to reload data.
Because I want to 'restart' the fragments. So the OnCreateView in every fragment is called again. (thus reloading the data in there)

Comment: I would put the setup code in onStart().  The onCreate() and/or onCreateView() methods will just inflate the layout and wire up the widgets (the findViewById() stuff).

Comment: I just figured out you can use OnStart in fragments... I am new to Android so yeah... Anyhow, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Just put this code inside

> onResume()

For example you want to update your listview when u return to your fregment.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (allowRefresh)
    {
        allowRefresh = false;
        lst_applist = db.load_apps();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}
```

Here **getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();**

This line detach and re-attach the fragment so your content will be updated.

Comment: How do I do that from the activity?

Comment: what can i write (this) here

Comment: If you want to move this logic into the Activity, do it inside the [onPostResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity#onpostresume) method to avoid the [Activity state lost error](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Comment: What's missing from this answer are the other locations where you would need to change the value of `allowRefresh`. In this case, in `onPause` it should be `true` and then in`onDestroyView` it should be `false`

Answer (score 2):

The `onResume()` get called always before the fragment is displayed. Even when the fragment is created for the first time . So you can simply move your from `onViewCreated()` to `onResume`.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

//move your code from onViewCreated() here 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mehul But u can alse do it this way .if you want to replace your fragment you could just say

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (allowRefresh)
    {
        allowRefresh = false;
        lst_applist = db.load_apps();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(Fragment_Container,fragment).commit();
    }
}
```