# How to update a tab layout before switching to another tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, tabs

I'm working on a project that has tab fragments in android. They are A,B,C and D.So the problem comes when I click tab B there is a button called **"like"** when this button direct to another activity. There we can **like** or **unlike** friends. When the back button clicked on that activity the tab B fragment should be updated automatically.

I referred so much in the internet but couldn't find a suitable answer to me. 
I'm very new to android so I'm asking for your help thanks..

I use this code onResume

```
public void onResume()
    {  // After a pause OR at startup

        super.onResume();
        setbList(bLikedList);
        getBLiked();
        bListAdapter = new bListAdapter(getActivity(), bLikedList);
        listView.setAdapter(bListAdapter);
        //Refresh your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: the idea is to save the state and the onResume method of your activity pull the current state and redraw your fragment

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598219/how-to-refresh-fragments-onresume

Comment: this reference what is  "lst_applist = db.load_apps(); " line does can you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `SetCurrentItem(int i)` for [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) on Call of `OnResume()`